# How to check an existing record in the database and setFlash in yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want to check if the book has been borrowed. So i don't want the same book to be posted twice. as for now it shows an error of duplication,How can i capture that error after checking its existance.

```
 public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Books();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'book_id' => $model->book_id]);
    }

    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: What error? Show your validation rules.

Comment: It can't check it before it get posted into the database. Give me your skype id please. It might be easier

Comment: If record is saved to DB, then you don't have any validation errors. If you have validation errors, `$model->save()` will return `false` and record will not be saved. You can get list of errors using `$model->getErrors()` (see answer bellow).

Answer (score 0):

To get model validation errors, you can call `$model->validate()`. You can then get errors with `$model->getErrors()`. However, as pointed in comments, `save()` also calls `validate()`, so the sample you provided should look like this:

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
    return $this->redirect(['view', 'book_id' => $model->book_id]);
} else {
    $errors = $model->getErrors();
    //Process your errors here
}
```

Detailed info can be found in official docs for [Class yii\base\Model #validate](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-model#validate()-detail)

Comment: `save()` calls `validate()`, so separating these calls does not really change anything.